# TypeError: this is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following 2 files `root/functions/util/constants.js` and `root/functions/handlers/images.js`. The following are their source code

**images.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const os = require("os");
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const { uuid } = require("uuidv4");
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const config = require("../util/config");

const gcs = new Storage({
  projectId: config.projectId
});

const bucket = gcs.bucket(config.storageBucket);


const {
  INVALID_TYPE_MESSAGE,
  POST_SMALL_IMAGE_TYPE,
  POST_MEDIUM_IMAGE_TYPE,
  select_size_from_type
} = require("../util/constants");


const {
  USER_PUBLIC_PROFILE_IMAGE
} = require("../util/schema")

const {error_response} = require("../util/validators");


exports.async_resize = async function(url, type) {

  const size = select_size_from_type(type);//code beyond this are not executed
//some other code...
```

**constants.js**

```
const {error_response} = require("./validators");
const { admin } = require("./admin")

//Entity and collection names

//also contains fields of maps of schemas

const {
  USER_PUBLIC_PROFILE_IMAGE
} = require("./schema");


const LIKES_COLLECTION = "likes";
const COMMENTS_COLLECTION = "comments";
const POSTS_COLLECTION = "posts";
const NOTIFICATIONS_COLLECTION = "notifications";

const FOLLOWERS = "followers";
const FOLLOWING = "following";
const PUBLIC_FOLLOWERS_SUBCOLLECTION = FOLLOWERS;
const PUBLIC_FOLLOWING_SUBCOLLECTION = FOLLOWING;
const USERS_PUBLIC_COLLECTION = "users_public";
const USERS_PRIVATE_COLLECTION = "users_private";
const PRIVATE_FOLLOWERS_SUBCOLLECTION = FOLLOWERS;
const PRIVATE_FOLLOWING_SUBCOLLECTION = FOLLOWING;

const LIKE_TYPE = "like";
const COMMENT_TYPE = "comment";
const POST_TYPE = "post";
const NOTIFICATION_TYPE = "notification"


const POST_SMALL_IMAGE_TYPE = "small";
const POST_MEDIUM_IMAGE_TYPE = "medium";
const POST_MAXIMUM_ORIGINAL_TYPE = "original";



const SERVER_TIME = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();


const INVALID_TYPE_MESSAGE = "Invalid recipient type";

const select_collection_from_type = (type) => {
  if (type === LIKE_TYPE) {
    return LIKES_COLLECTION;
  } else if (type === POST_TYPE) {
    return POSTS_COLLECTION;
  } else if (type === COMMENT_TYPE) {
    return COMMENTS_COLLECTION;
  } else {
    return error_response("Data type is not within scope of project");
  }
}


//can be used for profile_image also
const select_size_from_type = function (type) {
  if (type === POST_SMALL_IMAGE_TYPE) {
    return 64;
  } else if (type === POST_MEDIUM_IMAGE_TYPE) {
    return 128;
  } else if (type === POST_MAXIMUM_ORIGINAL_TYPE) {
    return 256;
  } else if (type === USER_PUBLIC_PROFILE_IMAGE) {
    return 1; //same as before, need a better number for this
    //
  } else {
    return error_response("Data type is not within scope of project");
  }
}


module.exports = {
  LIKE_TYPE,
  LIKES_COLLECTION,
  COMMENT_TYPE,
  COMMENTS_COLLECTION,
  PUBLIC_FOLLOWERS_SUBCOLLECTION,
  PUBLIC_FOLLOWING_SUBCOLLECTION,
  PRIVATE_FOLLOWERS_SUBCOLLECTION,
  PRIVATE_FOLLOWING_SUBCOLLECTION,
  USERS_PUBLIC_COLLECTION,
  USERS_PRIVATE_COLLECTION,
  POST_TYPE,
  POSTS_COLLECTION,
  INVALID_TYPE_MESSAGE,
  SERVER_TIME,
  NOTIFICATIONS_COLLECTION,
  POST_SMALL_IMAGE_TYPE,
  POST_MEDIUM_IMAGE_TYPE,
  POST_MAXIMUM_ORIGINAL_TYPE,
  select_collection_from_type,
  select_size_from_type
};
```

I tried running a script and it keeps telling me that

```
TypeError: select_size_from_type is not a function
    at exports.async_resize (/Users/Isaac/root/functions/handlers/images.js:36:16)
```

but I really dont see any syntax error. I'm using Webstorm and the functions can be navigated. Can someone enlighten me what else can be the cause of the syntax error?

**Update**

I also tried `console.log(select_size_from_type);` in `images.js`, `console.log(select_size_from_type);` before it was exported in `constants.js`. It prints `undefined` and `[Function: select_size_from_type]` respectively. Even when I tried changing the signature of `async_resize` as well as `select_size_from_type`, all of them gave the same error as well. Any other function which does not involve `select_size_from_type` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Functions can be defined in two ways

Way 1

```
function my_function_name (arguments) {
   ...function body
}
```

Way 2

```
const my_function_name = function (arguments) {
   ... function body
}
```

In your case, it seems like you are trying to mix both the ways.

Try changing your function definition to

```
exports.async_resize = async(url, type) => {
   ...function body

}
```

Comment: I just tried that fix and it doesn't work. I used to write in similar formats of  `exports.async_resize = async function(url, type) {` in other functions and they still work perfectly

Comment: What about the other functions. Does `select_collection_from_type` function behave the same way?

Comment: His function declaration isn't the problem. Look up "anonymous function expression".

Comment: @IshantSolanki Tried calling a function that uses `select_collection_from_type` and it does work

Comment: Thats strange. The only difference between the two functions is the one that works follows the arrow syntax while other other doesnt. Changing `select_size_from_type` to arrow function also didnt work i suppose? Also, can you name it to something else just to debug like `temp`?

Comment: Yeap, I tried the arrow syntax too. Renaming the entire function to `temp` still gives it undefined.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  const size = this.select_size_from_type(type);//code beyond this are not executed
```

or export your file like this

```
 module.exports.select_size_from_type=select_size_from_type
```

or

```
module.exports={size_type : select_size_from_type}
```

and then require it like this

```
const getsizefromtype=require(....) 
select_size_from_type= getsizefromtype.size_type
```

Comment: I tried both ways, the first in `images.js` and the second in `constants.js` and just applying it for that single function. Both solutions dont work for me

Comment: what does console.log(this.select_size_from_type()) shows?

Comment: also you can try  `module.exports={size_type : select_size_from_type} `and then require it like this `const getsizefromtype=require(....) , select_size_from_type= getsizefromtype.size_type`

Comment: To your first comment, it will not be able to execute because it was undefined in the first place. For the 2nd suggestion, are you trying to get me to give up the destructuring syntax?